# How to grab all regex matches in php?

Tags: php, regex

```
$pattern = '/b+[^\s-]*/';
$subject = 'brew and this is bunny';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
```

Clearly, brew and bunny should match, but $matches only contains brew.

What should I do to have $matches contain all regex matches

Comment: [preg_match_all()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `+` after `b` in your regex.

```
$str = 'brew and this is bunny';
preg_match_all('/b[^\s]+/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => brew
            [1] => bunny
        )
)
```